# Celery pool processes, tasks, and system processes & memory space

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd

Each task execution in a unique process space?

- Do Celery pool (not Master) processes spawn off a process for each task execution?
- In other words, is each task execution through a new process spawned by worker pool process?

Or is it the other way?

- task is executed as part of worker pool process?
- One implication of that: If celery task relies on data stored in the process memory space, that data is part of the worker pool process which is executing it. And, all tasks executed by the worker pool process have access to that copy of the data.

Answer (score 1):

These details depend on the [concurrency model](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) you pick for your workers.

In the default, prefork model (based on processes), every task is executed inside one of the pre-forked processes (worker processes). So yes - it is a process pool. You can configure Celery to create a new worker-process for each task, but that is not the default behaviour. By default Celery does not replace old worker processes with new ones, but you can control that with the [worker_max_tasks_per_child](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-max-tasks-per-child) setting.

Comment: Thanks @DejanLekic. I wasn't sure, especially with the part of the doc "Where -n worker1@example.com -c2 -f %n-%i.log will result in three log files". This seem to indicate, pool process is same as each worker process. In other words, worker process and pool processes seem to be synonymous?